# why eq not working in jquery while using after?

Tags: javascript, jquery

why eq not working in jquery while using after ?I am inserting my `html` using `after` on button click .I tried like that

```
$(function(){
$('#btn').click(function(){
  $(".topics-content").children("ul").eq(0).find("li").eq(3).after($(".reco_inlineslider.show34").eq(0));

})
});
```

here is my code
https://jsbin.com/cenegabale/edit?html,js,output

**current out after button click**

```
1
2
3
   11
   dddd
    22
    33
4
5
6
```

**Expected output**

```
1
2
3
  11
  22
  33
4
dddd
5
6
```

I want to insert `html` after `4` text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `.find("li").eq(3)` use `.cildren("li").eq(3)`, find will search in all nested element, while children will consider the immediate children.

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
$(function(){
$('#btn').click(function(){
$(".topicscontent").children("ul").eq(0).children("li").eq(3).after($(".reco_inlineslider.show34").eq(0));
})
});
```

or use

```
find(6)
```

instead of

```
find(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the `find("li")` finds all the lis inside of the ul, not just its children.

So you either need to use `.children('li')` like you have for the ul or `.find('> li')`